# xcode 6.1.1 new class naming sctructure

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I made a new class called "SignInView" by going to

- CMD + n
- iOS: Source
- "m" Objective-C File
- Next
- File: SignInView
- File Type: Category
- Class: `UIView`

And what I get back are two new files:

- UIView+SignInView.h
- UIView+SignInView.m

I added these to my project target in build phases but these aren't picked up in my SignInView.xib when I set the main most view's custom class to "SignInView". I've tried "UIView+SignInView" as well but none of it is getting picked up. How am I supposed to add a custom class of this style name to Interface Builder?

Comment: You've added a category, not a class. Was the option offered to you?

Comment: @Tommy The options were `Empty File`, `Category`, `Protocol`, and `Extension` of which only `Category` and `Extension` are the only two which allow a "subclass" like option but both do the same name scheme where `Extension` only gives you the `.h` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Xcode 6, Apple has distinguished classes from other kinds of file. You want to go command+n -> Cocoa Touch Class and follow through there. Unintuitively, Apple does not offer the ability to create an Objective-C class within the 'Objective-C File' template.